# Looping through many workbooks in a folder in order to copy data from them to a main workbook

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm trying to loop through a folder, find all workbooks which have the word "inspection" in them, and then copy contents from those workbooks in a master workbook. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub FolderLoop()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim myPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myName As String
Dim myCounter As Integer
Dim myCounterRange As Range
Dim myCounter2 As Integer


myCounter = 0

myPath = Dir("C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\2017_InspectionReports")

For Each wb In myPath
    myName = wb.Name
    If InStr(1, myName, ins) <> 0 Then

        For Each myCounterRange In wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
            If myCounterRange.Value <> "" Then
                myCounter = myCounter + 1
            End If
        Next myCounterRange

        myCounter2 = Workbooks("Inspection_Report.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4", "S" & myCounter).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Inspection_Report.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("A" & myCounter2)
    End If

    myCounter = 0
    myCounter2 = 0

    Next wb


End Sub
```

The error I am getting is at `For Each wb In myPath` where it says:

> *For each can only iterate through an object collection or a table*

...or something similar, I'm translating from another language.

Comment: Dir returns the first file you cannot loop on one thing, to loop with Dir() you call it again with no arguments.  You will want a Do Loop or while loop:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As per Scott Craner's comment try it this way:

```
myPath = Dir("C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\2017_InspectionReports") 'Fetches the first item

While myPath <> ""

    ... your code here ...

    myPath = Dir()   'Fetches the next item

Wend
```

Within the loop you'll need to set `wb` to be the relevant workbook from the name of the workbook which will be stored in the `myPath` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty close to what you want.  Just modify it to suit your specific needs.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm